# On unsaved changes popup 'cancle click' need to set the previous value in dropdown

Tags: angular, routes, angular-material, dropdown

I have the following use cases. We are using single page angular application.

**e.g.**

It contained the dropdown which has some sensitive information on the change of dropdown we need to load the subviews as mostly sub views contained the reactive forms. The requirement is if sub views having reactive form and user make any changes in form and change the parent dropdown then to show the 'Navigation Un-Saved changes popup' with cancel and Ok button.

If the user clicks on the Ok button the dropdown change will fire and load respective subviews. If the user clicks on cancel button the user stay on the same view and drop down need to be reset with the previous value. Mostly we use conductive guard but don't know how to set the previous value in the dropdown as we are using Angular material dropdown. Any help for such use case would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you supply us with some sample code or a stackblitz demonstrating what you’ve tried?